# OnMouseDown не вызывается

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нажимаю на обьект на который повешен скрипт, и ничего не происходит. Объект двумерный.

Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class omsd : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
          Debug.Log("Has been click.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Первый абзац можно опустить, не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы данный колбек работал, нужно к игровому объекту прикрепить коллайдер, о чем явно указано в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html):

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while
>   over the GUIElement or **Collider**.

Там еще написано про GUI объекты, но, судя по вопросу, это не ваш случай.

Comment: Я добавил Box Collider. От этого ничего не случилось. Коллайдер поставлен на весь обьект.

Comment: Попробуйте перезапустить Unity, если не поможет - пересоздайте объект. Единственная вещь, которая может мешать вызову OnMouseDown - другие коллайдеры на пути.